# Does acceleration of a permanent magnet generate electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Imagine a permanent magnet attached to the edge of a disc, such as a vinyl record on a record player (remember those?).  If the disc were to be spun, thereby accelerating the permanent magnet, would electromagnetic radiation be generated?  Let's assume that the disc is spinning in free space, so there are no nearby conductors.

This is to settle a disagreement that I have with someone else.  We agree that if an ordinary permanent magnet were to be attached to a disc made of ordinary material about the size of a record and spun at a few thousand RPMs at most, that any electromagnetic radiation would be fantastically weak, and that such a device would not be a practical electromagnetic radiator.  The question is whether any meaningful electromagnetic radiation would be generated at all as a result of the spinning.  (By "meaningful" I mean large enough to be detected by currently-available technology.)  Black-body radiation doesn't count.

Comment: What counts as "meaningful"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=magnet+spinning+electromagnetic+radiation?+site:physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not only electromagnetic waves, but also gravitational ones (gravitons!).